# PHP GET Data Fowarding

Tags: php, html

I have set up a website in a way that leaves the user on a confirmation page to submit form data with the GET data present in the URL of the confirmation page (It's nothing sensitive). I'd like it so that upon pushing a button, the GET data on that page's URL is sent to another URL, is this possible?

I could probably just copy and paste the form and set it to be hidden and set the values to the individual values but that isn't what I want to do because it'd create extra work in the future adding more form inputs.

Edit:
Here is the code for the form:

```
<form action="confirmrequest.php">
        <div id="extracontact">
            <h4>Please choose a method of contacting you in the event more detail from you is required</h4>
            <select name="socialmediatype" required>
                <option>-Choose an option below-</option>
                <option value="Instagram">Instagram</option>
                <option value="Snapchat">Snapchat</option>
                <option value="Whatsapp">Whatsapp</option>
                <option value="Skype">Skype</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <br>
            Platform Username (or phone for Whatsapp):<br>
            <input type="text" name="contactpin" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <h4>Please enter your email address to receive confirmation email & download link</h4>
            <br>
            Email Address<br>
            <input type="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
            <h4>Which type of art style are you requesting?</h4>
            <input type="radio" name="style" value="Lineart" required> Lineart - $5<br>
            <input type="radio" name="style" value="Coloured"> Coloured - $6<br>
            <input type="radio" name="style" value="Background & Shading"> Background/Shading - $7<br><br>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h4>Please include a full description of what you would like</h4>
            <textarea name="description" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
        </div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit Request">
    </form>
```

Comment: Do you have any code that you've already tried?

Comment: ```<a href="(...)?<?php echo htmlentities(http_build_query($_GET),ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);?>" id="whatever" /> <button onclick="Javascript:document.getElementById('whatever').click();" value="clickhere" />```